# How to swap out data via unload and load in C3.js

Tags: c3.js

I'm trying to swap out data sets in a C3.js graph.

The code I assumed would work based on the C3 docs looks like this:

```
chart.unload();
chart.load({ 
  columns: [
    ['data3', 100, 90, 80, 70, 60, 50]
  ] 
});
```

But this doesn't work. You'll notice that the graph rendered on the following Plunkr renders improperly, so I'm clearly doing something wrong: https://jsfiddle.net/7rfm9om9/

What is the idiomatic way to replace data in a C3 chart?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Ah, it appears that `chart.unload()` does some asynchronous work that, if you call `chart.load()` immediately after in a synchronous fashion, will break the graph.

I got this working by loading the new data in a function passed to `chart.unload`'s `done` callback.

```
chart.unload({
    done: function() {
      chart.load({ 
        columns: [
          ['data3', 100, 90, 80, 70, 60, 50]
        ] 
      });  
    }
  });
```

Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1g5v1s24/1/

Answer (score 13):

According to the c3 documentation, the way to do this is to use the unload param of the load function.

```
chart.load({
  unload: true,
  columns: ['data1', 100]
});
```

There are issues with rendering and animations otherwise when trying to use .unload() and then .load().

This note is included in the .unload() documentation:

http://c3js.org/reference.html#api-unload

> Note: If you call [the] load API soon after/before unload, unload
>   param of load should be used. Otherwise chart will not be rendered
>   properly because of [cancelation] of animation.
>
> done will be called after data loaded, but it's not after rendering.
>   It's because rendering will finish after some transition and there is
>   some time lag between loading and rendering.

According to the documentation for .load():

http://c3js.org/reference.html#api-load

> If unload given, data will be unloaded before loading new data. If
>   true given, all of data will be unloaded. If target ids given as
>   String or Array, specified targets will be unloaded.
>
> Note: unload should be used if some data needs to be unloaded
>   simultaneously. If you call unload API soon after/before load instead
>   of unload param, chart will not be rendered properly because of cancel
>   of animation.

Format would be along the lines of the following snippets:

All Data

```
chart.load({
  unload: true,
  columns: [
    ['data3', 100, 90, 80, 70, 60, 50]
  ] 
});
```

Specified Targets

```
chart.load({
  unload: ['data1', 'data2'],
  columns: [
    ['data3', 100, 90, 80, 70, 60, 50]
  ] 
});
```

JSFiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/d8g015n2/

Comment: In my case `unload: true` did not work out, but specifying the exact ids to unload --- did deliver the desired result. Thankfully I know all ids of my data.