# Tooltip in C3 Charts does not refresh

Tags: javascript, angularjs, c3.js

We use the bar chart capabilities of c3 charts library in an environment where live data is floating in. This did lead to a problem where if a user hovers over a bar **the bar itself did update but not the tooltip** that was shown. Is there a way to update/reload the tooltip?[image]

@Update 1:
Sorry for the delayed response. Basically we have an observer listening for data changes. This will trigger a method called reload which has the following lines (how the data looks like is shown in the comments):

```
chart.load({
            xs: xs, // AmberViolation:"facilityId",BlueViolation:"facilityId",RedViolation:"facilityId"
            columns: columns, // [["facilityId", "SUB-GTW"],["RedViolation", 0],["BlueViolation", 2],["AmberViolation", 0]]
                    unload: _.difference(drawnChartYCols, nextDrawColumns),
            types: types, // AmberViolation:"bar",BlueViolation:"bar",RedViolation:"bar"
            colors: colors,
            done: function () {
                if (columns.length && columns[0].length > 10) {
                    chart.zoom([0, 11]);
                    d3.select(element[0]).selectAll('svg > g').filter(function(d, i) { return i === 1 }).attr('display', null);
                    chart.resize({width: $scope.width, height: $scope.height});
                            d3.select(element[0]).select('.extent').attr('x', 0);
                } else {
                    chart.unzoom();
                    d3.select(element[0]).selectAll('svg > g').filter(function(d, i) { return i === 1 }).attr('display', 'none');
                    chart.resize({width: $scope.width, height: $scope.height + 70});
                }
            }
});
chart.groups([groups]);// ["RedViolation","BlueViolation","AmberViolation"]
```

@Update 2:

You can even see that behavior on http://c3js.org/samples/chart_bar_stacked.html. **Just hover over one of the bars while data is being updated and let the mouse stay there. The tooltip will not update.** Only if you move the mouse again it will refresh.[image]

@Update 3: Since this happens even on examples of c3 charts I created a bug on Github: https://github.com/c3js/c3/issues/2307

Comment: do you use `.load(args)` on your chart to load the new data coming in? http://c3js.org/reference.html#api-load

Comment: Yes, we use chart.load and update xs, columns, unload, types and colors with it.

Comment: you might get more help on this question if you included a minimal, complete, and verifiable example to go along with your problem https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Please have a look at http://c3js.org/samples/chart_bar_stacked.html and hover over one of the bars while data is being updated and let the mouse stay there. You'll see that the tooltip won't update.

Answer (score 0):

You don't provide any code snippet so it's hard to answer. I guess you don't update your data properly. According to the documentation:

> If you call load API soon after/before unload, unload param of load
>   should be used. Otherwise chart will not be rendered properly because
>   of cancel of animation.

Something like this, **to unload the old values**, could solve your problem:

```
chart.load({
  unload: true,
  columns: ['data1', 100]
});
```

Check out this [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38234537/8427374) on SO.

Comment: Hi thanks for your response. I tried using unload: true just to check but this also didn't cause the tooltip to be neither.

Comment: I have faced a similar issue by the past, where data weren't un/loading even if I called un/load() and it may be a bug from c3js. See https://github.com/c3js/c3/issues/975
What you can try is to use `flush()`, or `resize` (and keep `unload = true`)
If it is possible for your usage, maybe deleting the chart and creating It again using `chart.generate()` instead of `chart.load` can solve the problem...

Answer (score 0):

My current solution is to hide and show the tooltip once the data gets updated in order to refresh it. Its ugly since the user can see the position of the tooltip jumping.

```js
var currentIndex = null;
var chart = c3.generate({
    data: {
        columns: [
            ['data1', 20],
            ['data2', 30],
            ['data3', 40]
        ],
        type: 'bar',
        groups: [
            ['data1', 'data2', 'data3']
        ],
        onmouseover: function(e) {
          currentIndex = e.index;
    },
        onmouseout: function(e) {
         currentIndex = null;
        }
    },
    axis: {
       y: {
        show: true,
       },
       x: {
        show: true,
        type: ({
         NUMERIC: 'indexed',
         TEXT: 'category',
         DATE: 'timeseries'
        })['TEXT']
       }
      },
      bar: {
       width: {
        ratio: 0.9,
        max: 100
       }
      },
      padding: {
       top: 25,
       right: 25
      },
      zoom: {enabled: false},
      subchart: {
       show: true,
       axis: {
        x: {
         show: false
        }
       }
      },
      legend: {
       show: false
      },
      line: {
       connectNull: true
      },
      transition: {
       duration: null
      },
      grid: {
       y: {
        show: true
       }
      }
});

setTimeout(function () {
    chart.load({
        columns: [['data1', 30],
            ['data2', 10],
            ['data3', 10]]
    });
    
    if (currentIndex != null) {
     chart.tooltip.hide();
     chart.tooltip.show({x: currentIndex});
    }
    
}, 3000);
```

```html
<link href="https://rawgit.com/masayuki0812/c3/master/c3.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/masayuki0812/c3/master/c3.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="chart"></div>
```

I added a hover listener where I get the currentHoverIndex and a onmouseout listener to set currentHoverIndex to null so we don't accidently show a tooltip if user doesn't hover on a bar at that time.